# Openstack policy.json File

Tags: cloud, devops, openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-keystone

I have installed two versions of **Devstack** and one version of **Openstack** in my private cloud lab, the point is for **Nova** or **Horizon** I can't find any policy file, (due to new versions it have been removed I guess) cause it is not in `/etc/nova` or `/etc/horizon` and for other tools like **Keystone** and **Glance** when I change the policies for special role it doesn't affect.

Could anyone help me with these to points?

Comment: Please have a look at this post [Can't find /etc/nova/policy.json](https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/102501/cant-find-etcnovapolicyjson/)

Answer (score 0):

I found it in the **Opendev** forum, which says in these versions there is no `policy.sjon` file and you can either create or generate one and that becomes the master file. and it worked for me.
You can run `oslopolicy-policy-generator --namespace nova` for generating or copy from https://docs.openstack.org/mitaka/config-reference/compute/policy.json.html